# Вибивает ошибку при парсинге json файла на swift

Tags: json, swift

```
import Foundation

struct Response:Codable{
    let candidates: [Candidate]
}

struct Candidate: Codable
{
    struct geometry:Codable
    {
        struct location:Codable{
             let lat:Double
             let lng:Double 
        }
    
    }
    let name: String
}


var inputData="""
{
"candidates" : [
{
"geometry" : {
"location" : {
"lat" : 48.470247,
"lng" : 35.036206
}
},
"name" : "Coffee Life"
},
{
"geometry" : {
"location" : {
"lat" : 48.469434,
"lng" : 35.038985
}
},
"name" : "Have Coffee"
},
{
"geometry" : {
"location" : {
"lat" : 48.466561,
"lng" : 35.045186
}
},
"name" : "AROMA KAVA"
},
{
"geometry" : {
"location" : {
"lat" : 48.463783,
"lng" : 35.042595
}
},
"name" : "Mr. Coffee"
},
{
"geometry" : {
"location" : {
"lat" : 48.463516,
"lng" : 35.048889
}
},
"name" : "DoubleDecker"
},
{
"geometry" : {
"location" : {
"lat" : 48.425694,
"lng" : 35.025487
}
},
"name" : "Mocco bar"
},
{
"geometry" : {
"location" : {

"lat" : 48.451214,
"lng" : 35.057789
}
},
"name" : "Confetti"
},
{
"geometry" : {
"location" : {
"lat" : 48.460239,
"lng" : 35.069301
}
},
"name" : "One dollar bar"
},
{
"geometry" : {
"location" : {
"lat" : 48.459414,
"lng" : 35.064731
}
},
"name" : "Heisenberg Coffee Lab"
},
{
"geometry" : {
"location" : {
"lat" : 48.423311,
"lng" : 35.058121
}
},
"name" : "Sopranos"
}]
}
"""

let data = try JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: inputData.data(using: .utf8)!)
```

Скажите правильная у меня структура Candidate и если правильная то как мне обращаться к координатам?

Answer (score 0):

Никакой ошибки у вас нет, обратиться можете например к первому элементу так: `data.candidates.first`